# What is simple way to fail a build when a property is not set?

Tags: maven-2

As stated in the title, how can I modify - in the simplest manner possible - a `pom.xml` in order to make it fails if a property is not set in the command line.

For example, `mvn clean package` will fail, when `mvn clean package -Dfoo=bar` will succeed.

I'm looking for something like the `<prerequisites/>` [tag](http://maven.apache.org/ref/2.0.4/maven-model/maven.html#class_prerequisites) in the `pom.xml` (except that `<prerequisites/>` only allow me to check the Maven version)...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the [requireProperty goal of the maven-enforcer-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireProperty.html) to fail a build if a property is missing.

Note this only requires that the property is set, so it could have been set in the pom's properties section.

Comment: Yes, for one property in my project, I've set a default value, which can be overriden by the user. However, I really need that the user specifies another property, so that's why I wanted to find a way to fail the build if the user forgot this propery.