# How to make a systemPropertyVariables mandatory

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-plugin

Properties listed under systemPropertyVariables in maven-surefire-plugin, how to make them mandatory? In the below code how can I make variable "path" mandatory?

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <Path>${path}</Path>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: [What is simple way to fail a build when a property is not set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398407/what-is-simple-way-to-fail-a-build-when-a-property-is-not-set) ?